# Red5. No scope with my project

Tags: scope, red5

i can't create my application with Red5 server. I've got an error

```
NetConnection.Connect.Rejected: No scope 'TestEcho' on this server.
NetConnection.Connect.Closed
```

I did something like ping application to test that everything works fine. My class looks like this:

```
 package org.red5.core;

import org.red5.server.adapter.ApplicationAdapter;
import org.red5.server.api.IConnection;
import org.red5.server.api.IScope;
import org.red5.server.api.service.ServiceUtils;

public class Application extends ApplicationAdapter {

    public void appDisconnect(IConnection conn)
    {
        super.appDisconnect(conn);
    }


    public boolean appStart()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public void appStop()
    {}


    public boolean appConnect(IConnection conn, Object[] params)
    {
        return true;
    }


    public Object echo(Object p)
    {
        return p;
    }

}
```

Also i have red5-web.xml and red5-web.properties

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>

    <!--
    Defines a properties file for dereferencing variables
    -->
    <bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/red5-web.properties" />
    </bean>

    <!--
    Defines the web context
    -->
    <bean id="web.context" class="org.red5.server.Context" 
        autowire="byType" />

    <!--
    Defines the web scopes
    -->
    <bean id="web.scope" class="org.red5.server.WebScope"
         init-method="register">
        <property name="server" ref="red5.server" />
        <property name="parent" ref="global.scope" />
        <property name="context" ref="web.context" />
        <property name="handler" ref="web.handler" />
        <property name="contextPath" value="${webapp.contextPath}" />
        <property name="virtualHosts" value="${webapp.virtualHosts}" />
    </bean>

    <!--
    Defines the web handler which acts as an applications endpoint
    -->
    <bean id="web.handler" 
        class="org.red5.core.Application" 
        singleton="true" />

</beans>
```

And

```
webapp.contextPath=/TestEcho
webapp.virtualHosts=127.0.0.1
```

So, it's strange but in echo-demo application i can't get connection to rtmp://localhost:1935/TestEcho 
And i'd like to notice that demo applications work good, for example, oflaDemo. Where is the problem?....

Answer (score 3):

which version do you use?
if you use red5 1.0,  please  use

```
<bean id="web.scope" class="org.red5.server.scope.WebScope" init-method="register">
```

instead of

```
<bean id="web.scope" class="org.red5.server.WebScope" init-method="register">
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the below things

- check your folder name with in webapp folder. It should be "TestEcho"
- check webAppRootKey in your web.xml file
- enable debug in logback.xml in red5 conf folder. check your log while starting.

Ref: https://github.com/arulrajnet/red5Demo/wiki/Different-context-name

Answer (score 1):

I am a bigginer in Red5. I have also Struggled with the same problem. After searching Plenty of forums I have figured it out. In my searching process I have gone through your query also. So I thought it would be helpful if I post solution here.

The problem is with having duplicate red5.jar file. In my scenario I have one jar file in my RED5_HOME and the other in myapp/WEB-INF/lib folder. We should not have two Red5.jar files. red5.jar must be in RED5_HOME directory. So I have removed all the jars including red5.jar from myapp/WEB-INF/lib folder. It Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the very same issue, it was configuration issue with the virtualHost name.

I fixed by changing `red5-web.properties` from `webapp.virtualHosts=localhost` to `webapp.virtualHosts=*`.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Check something very simple - if you are on Windows - red5 installs and starts a services by default. Then you might have manually copied another version of red5 - which you use for development. That is what happened with me - there was a Windows Service - running red5 - long forgotten. Whereas I was actually running another version of red5 form my filesystem.